# Testcafe - how to read json response and enter value in selector

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, selector, testcafe

I try to get the value from the URL and insert it in the selector. 
Unfortunately, so far without success.

I have URL with some code:

```
https://example.com/apis/phone/code.json?mobile_number=22333
```

Data in the file looks like:

```
{"code": 111}
```

And I have a scenario:

```
test('Register', async t => {
  await t
    .typeText(registrationPage.input.firstName, firstName)
    .typeText(registrationPage.input.email, userEmail)
    .typeText(registrationPage.input.password, userPass)
    .typeText(registrationPage.input.mobileNumber, '22333')
    .click(registrationPage.button.next)
  await t
    .typeText('registrationPage', code)
});
```

The problem is that the new code is generated only after the phone number is given.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'data in the file looks like'?  Is that the response from the URL that is supplieD?  Or is that in another file?  In the 'typeText' function, what is 'code' you are passing?  Why is registrationPage in single quotes?  typeText expects a selector as first argument (which you aren't passing), then a string (which I don't think variable code is a string), and then other optional arguments. Seems like you aren't passing the correct parameters